# Dispatcher.Invoke fails

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm, dispatcher

I'm stuck at a problem when updating my View.

I have two DataGrids on which I have to add columns dynamically. To do that, I've added an Attached Property to the DataGrid that binds to an `ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>` and then wrote a custom ObjectToDataGridColumnConverter that converts an object (mostly strings) to a DataGridColumn and then adds this new column to the DataGrid.

It works fine with one of my two DataGrids. The other one (which is updated first) breaks on

```
var grid = source as DataGrid;
grid.Columns.Add(col);
```

with an InvalidOperationException:

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

Even if I try `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => grid.Columns.Add(col))` it breaks with the same exception.

My other DataGrid uses the same code to add its columns and it works fine. Even without any Invoke calls to the Dispatcher object.

Comment: If the ObservableCollection is updated in a background thread, you should indeed add the new column in the UI thread via a Dispatcher call. But it should then also be created in the UI thread, as it is itself a DispatcherObject.

Comment: The Collecttion that contains `col` is created inside my `ObjectToDataGridColumnConverter` so I assume that the UI thread owns this collection

Comment: It breaks _where_ with the same exception? Your code has multiple objects, and it's entirely possible you are getting the exception for different objects between the non-Invoke and Invoke scenarios. You should provide a more specific problem description, along with a better code example. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It breaks on `grid.Columns.Add(col)` with the same `InvalidOperationException`. I'm sure its the right object, since the references are equal.